# jcrfsuite training file format

Tags: java, machine-learning, crfsuite

From what I understand from the example of POS Tagging given in the examples of jcrfsuite. The training file is tab separated and first token is the label. But I do not get the BigCluster| thing. Can somebody help me with how to specify tokens in training file.

Example below:

O   BigCluster|00   BigCluster|0000 BigCluster|000000   BigCluster|00000000 BigCluster|0000000000   BigCluster|000000000000 BigCluster|00000000000000   BigCluster|0000000000000000 NextBigCluster|0100 NextBigCluster|01000101 NextBigCluster|010001011111 POSTagDict|D    POSTagDict|N    POSTagDict|^    POSTagDict|$    POSTagDict|G    NextPOSTag|V    1gramSuff|i 1gramPref|i prevword|    prevcurr||i  nextword|predict    nextword|predict    currnext|i|predict  Word|I  Lower|i Xxdshape|X  charclass|1,    first-shortcap  prevnext||predict    t=0

Test file format:

!   BigCluster|01   BigCluster|0110 BigCluster|011011   BigCluster|01101100 BigCluster|0110110011   BigCluster|011011001100 BigCluster|01101100110000   BigCluster|0110110011000000 NextBigCluster|1000 NextBigCluster|10001000 NextBigCluster|100010000000 POSTagDict|V    NextPOSTag|,    metaph_POSDict|N    1gramSuff|n 2gramSuff|nn    3gramSuff|mnn   4gramSuff|mmnn  5gramSuff|mmmnn 6gramSuff|ammmnn    7gramSuff|aammmnn   8gramSuff|aaammmnn  9gramSuff|daaammmnn 1gramPref|d 2gramPref|da    3gramPref|daa   4gramPref|daaa  5gramPref|daaam 6gramPref|daaamm    7gramPref|daaammm   8gramPref|daaammmn  9gramPref|daaammmnn prevword|    prevcurr||daaammmnn  nextword|.  nextword|.  currnext|daaammmnn|.    Word|Daaammmnn  Lower|daaammmnn Xxdshape|Xxxxxxxxx  charclass|1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,    first-initcap   prevnext||.  t=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is specified after the label is a list of feature-name and feature-value.
It is in a sparse representation instead of tabular representation.

BigCluster is just one of the features and it's relevant to the specific example only. You should create your own features if you are training from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that CRFsuite does not care for the naming convention nor feature design of labels and attributes, because treats them as strings.

CRFsuite learns weights of associations (feature weights) between attributes and labels, without knowing the meaning of labels and attributes. In other words, one can design and use arbitrary features just by writing label and attribute names in data sets, just find the best posible attributes for your example and run some experiments with different sets of attributes and features. And you will good to go.